# Функция return в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет! У меня есть код, который бежит по диапазону строк, при этом выкидывая `None`. Если не использовать `return` и `def`, то все работает отлично, но я не могу забрать полученные значения из функции в дальнейший код. Пример:

```
for i in range(19, 24):
    model_name = (sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value)
    if model_name != None:
        print(model_name)
```

Вывод:

```
Значение 1 
Значение 2 
...
```

Решил попробовать использовать `def` + `return`, но при этом получается, что забирается только первое значение из `range`. Пример:

```
def MD():
    for i in range(19, 24):
        model_name = (sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value)
        if model_name != None:
            return model_name

model_name = MD()
print(model_name)
```

Вывод:

```
Значение 1
```

Вопрос: Как сделать так, чтобы я смог вытащить все значения из функции в "глобальный" код, т.е. за ее пределы? Спасибо всем заранее!

P.S. Так же необходимо отсеивать `None`

Comment: Возвращайте список

Comment: Кстати, лучше использовать такое условие: `model_name is not None`, а функции называть в нижнем регистре.

Comment: вы путаете вывод функции и вывод в консоль

Answer (score 2):

Возвращайте список.

***Пример:***

```py
def md():
    result = []

    for i in range(19, 24):
        model_name = sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value
        if model_name is not None:
            result.append(model_name)
    return result
```

Comment: Данный код действительно помог, вот только он все значения собирает в одну строку, а до этого было каждое на новой. Видимо я неверно уточнил извините

Comment: @MaxZhukov Значения собираются в список. Если Вы хотите распечатать каждый элемент списка на новой строке, то воспользуйтесь циклами или сделайте так: `print(*md(), sep='\n')`.

Answer (score 2):

Можно обойтись и без промежуточного списка, если использовать оператор `yield`, с помощью которого можно вернуть из функции сколько угодно значений (включая бесконечное количество значений):

```
def get_models():
    for i in range(19, 24):
        model_name = (sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value)
        if model_name is None:
            yield model_name

for model_name in get_models():
    print(model_name)
```